# How do I push UIVIewController on modalViewController?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, iso

I have tabbar + navigation app. I call filterModalController:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:filterModalController animated:YES];
```

It appeared OK. Then I want to push officeController.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:officeController animated:YES];
```

But officeController didn't appeared. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that modal view controllers are not meant to push other view controllers, so you may want to think about the hierarchy of views you are using. Modals are meant to return to the parent view controller. You may need to call

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

before you push the officeViewController.

When I ran into this, I ended up pushing a Navigation controller as the modal view controller, with the 'filterModalController' as the root view controller. Since you already have a navigation controller, this may make things too confusing.

```
UINavigationController*  filterNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                            initWithRootViewController:filterModalController];

// Display the nav controller modally.
[self presentModalViewController:filterNavController animated:YES];

[locationNavController release];
```

Then the `filterNavController` can push your `officeController`.